# Compare two strings and highlight words which are different

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have two strings which are received via textboxes, Is there a way in vb.net to compare the two strings, and highlight in a different colour the differences?

What I have done so far is:

```
Dim txt1(textbox1.Text.Split(CType(" ", Char())).Length) As String
Dim txt2(textbox2.Text.Split(CType(" ", Char())).Length) As String
txt1 = textbox1.Text.Split(CType(" ", Char()))
txt2 = textbox2.Text.Split(CType(" ", Char()))

Dim diff1 As String = "" 'Differences between 1 and 2
Dim diff2 As String = "" 'Differences between 2 and 1

For Each diff As String In txt1
    If Array.IndexOf(txt2, diff.ToString) = -1 Then
        diff1 += diff.ToString & " - "
    End If
Next

For Each diff As String In txt2
    If Array.IndexOf(txt1, diff.ToString) = -1 Then
        diff2 += diff.ToString & " - "
    End If
Next
Response.Write("Difference in First To Second: " & diff1 & vbNewLine & "Difference in Second To First: " & diff2)
```

But I am trying to get the words which are different to be highlighted in the second textbox which are different from the first.

Help is appreciated :)

Comment: Why is html tagged?

Comment: **First of all**, your first four lines are unnecessary in their current state. [**`String.Split()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) creates an array of the necessary size, there's no need to calculate that beforehand (you're just wasting memory and processing power). **Secondly**, you can assign the resulting array directly at the same line where you declare your variable. **Finally**, `Split()` accepts a `ParamArray` of chars, so no need for the less readable `CType` conversion. -- Change your code to: `Dim txt1() As String = textbox1.Text.Split(" "c)`

Comment: Oh Okay yeah, any suggestions on how to do the highlight of different words?

Comment: @Chicken : This is ASP.NET, not WinForms. Please remember to check the tags. And FWIW you can use a [**`RichTextBox`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) to perform coloring, no need to create your own control.

Comment: @lanes123 : I have written an answer below, but bare in mind that it is very basic. A full text diff is not an easy thing to do.

Comment: @VisualVincent my appologies - I have removed comment not confuse anyone reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to perform highlighting directly in the `TextBox`, however you can do it outside using HTML.

Here's a little function I wrote for that. It utilizes a [**`Regex`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to iterate each word and apply HTML to the differing words:

```
Protected Function HighlightDifferences(ByVal Input As String, ByVal CompareTo As String, ByVal Color As String) As String
    Dim Prefix As String = "<span style=""color: " & Color & """>"
    Dim Suffix As String = "</span>"

    Dim Result As String = Input
    Dim WordRegex As New Regex("\S+", RegexOptions.Compiled)

    Dim StartIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim m As Match = WordRegex.Match(Result)

    While m IsNot Nothing AndAlso m.Success = True
        StartIndex = m.Index + m.Length

        If Regex.IsMatch(CompareTo, Regex.Escape(m.Value)) = False Then
            Result = Result.Insert(m.Index, Prefix).Insert(Prefix.Length + m.Index + m.Length, Suffix)
            StartIndex += Prefix.Length + Suffix.Length
        End If

        If StartIndex < Result.Length Then
            m = WordRegex.Match(Result, StartIndex)
        Else
            m = Nothing
        End If
    End While

    Return Result
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim Differences As String = HighlightDifferences(TextBox2.Text, TextBox1.Text, "#FF0000")
'Do something with the Differences variable, for instance output it to the page.
```

**Bare in mind** that this simply checks if each word in the first string exists in the second, meaning it doesn't care *where* a word is located nor *how many times* it occurs.

In order to do a complete difference check (for instance like Stack Overflow's edit revision system) you are faced with the [**LCS problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem). Writing a Diff algorithm is complicated, so if this is what you want then it is better to find an already existing .NET implementation of a Diff algorithm rather than trying to write your own.

### Page example (with screenshot)

**Page.aspx (body only):**

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h1 style="text-align: center">Text comparison tool</h1>
        <p style="text-align: center">Initial text:</p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="150px" Width="50%" TextMode="MultiLine" style="margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 25%">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</asp:TextBox><br/>

        <p style="text-align: center">Text to compare to:</p>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="150px" Width="50%" TextMode="MultiLine" style="margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 25%">The quick green fox jumps over the lazy cat</asp:TextBox>

        <p style="text-align: center;"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Find differences" /></p>

        <% 
            If Session("TextDiff") IsNot Nothing Then
        %>
        <div>
            <h1 style="text-align: center">Highlighted differences:</h1>
            <p style=" width: 50%; margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 25%"><%= Session("TextDiff") %></p>
        </div>
        <%
                Session.Remove("TextDiff")
            End If
        %>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Page.aspx.vb:**

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Session("TextDiff") = HighlightDifferences(TextBox2.Text, TextBox1.Text, "#FF0000")
End Sub

Protected Function HighlightDifferences(ByVal Input As String, ByVal CompareTo As String, ByVal Color As String) As String
    Dim Prefix As String = "<span style=""color: " & Color & """>"
    Dim Suffix As String = "</span>"

    Dim Result As String = Input
    Dim WordRegex As New Regex("\S+", RegexOptions.Compiled)

    Dim StartIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim m As Match = WordRegex.Match(Result)

    While m IsNot Nothing AndAlso m.Success = True
        StartIndex = m.Index + m.Length

        If Regex.IsMatch(CompareTo, Regex.Escape(m.Value)) = False Then
            Result = Result.Insert(m.Index, Prefix).Insert(Prefix.Length + m.Index + m.Length, Suffix)
            StartIndex += Prefix.Length + Suffix.Length
        End If

        If StartIndex < Result.Length Then
            m = WordRegex.Match(Result, StartIndex)
        Else
            m = Nothing
        End If
    End While

    Return Result
End Function
```

**Result:**

> [image: Text diff example]

Comment: Brilliant! works like a charm. Thank you very much, is there also a way to strip all punctuation from the input? Gives an error if the text has any brackets etc.

Comment: @lanes123 : An error? What kind of error and on what line?

Comment: A parsing error, if you were to compare 2 texts which contain brackets in .. the error would be.. "parsing "(text" - Not enough )'s."

Comment: @lanes123 : Oh, sorry about that. Mistake on my end. I've updated the code.

Comment: You mate, are a life saver! much appreciated. i am now trying to figure out a way to have them both as labels, and have the difference in the second label from 2 strings

Comment: @lanes123 : I'm not so sure you can put raw HTML in ASP.NET controls... I think you'd have to have Javascript help you with that. I don't know what the HTML equivalent of an `<asp:Label>` is, but you can try giving it a `ClientID` then write a piece of Javascript that sets its `innerHTML` to the diff text from my function.

Comment: Bare in mind that this simply checks if each word in the first string exists in the second, meaning it doesn't care where a word is located nor how many times it occurs. -- Is there a way to get around this issue to make it a bit more accurate?

Comment: @lanes123 : Read the next paragraph.

Comment: telerik offer a diff algorithm, which worked like a charm. Thank you for your help! @Visual Vincent

Comment: @lanes123 : No problem. Glad I could help! Good luck!